# fetch the contents from a url after every 30 seconds without reloading the page

Tags: php, curl

Fetching contents from a URL using cURL is done but i am not able to get a solution on how to fetch the URL after every 30 seconds without reloading the page.

Comment: You can use ajax which calls every 30 seconds using `setinterval`

Comment: Sir can i do this for only a part of the php code.. because the url is fetched in a function and i want that to be done after every 30 seconds

Comment: I will try this out. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score -1):

Be warned this is an infinite loop!

```
do {

  // curl code here
  sleep(30);

} while (true);
```